# Can an e-commerce site owner be guilty of a crime if the site is hacked?

Tags: criminal-law, hacking

Are there any crimes that could apply to a site owner if his e-commerce site is hacked?

Comment: What jurisdiction?

Comment: It's not unheard of, at least in the united states. https://www.ftc.gov/news-events/press-releases/2003/06/guess-settles-ftc-security-charges-third-ftc-case-targets-false

Comment: What kind of website are you running? What kind of information is stored on it? Please [edit] your question to add this information.

Comment: thanks folks to re-edit the question , it is much better...

website is just like mix with fiverr.com and ebay. information stored are, display name, username, email and password. the website gives users a facility to create products and sell online and advertise services. payment method is through paypal. i dont hold any personal such as address etc..

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but even though the question is little detailed, I'd propose a few inputs on the matter.

First, it's important to differ **crime** and **judicial punishment** the same way we divide **criminal court** and **civil court**. It's important to note that *usually* a crime requires intent (with obvious exception of crimes against life); that is, to commit a crime you are required to be **motivated**, be interested in the outcome, to have the *intention* to do it. On the other hand, **civil courts** won't bother to limit themselves to your wishes, if damages were caused, damages might required to be repared.

What we can conclude is that it's more likely for the owner to be held accountable for the **damages** he caused in a civil court rather than a criminal one. Although the website was hacked, the information stored there is in the owner's responsibility. The more sensible the data stolen is, the more damages it might cause.

Answer (score -3):

It would depend on the jurisdiction and on the degree of incompetence and negligence that led to the hack. If password are *stored*, that is to me gross negligence with a significant legal risk.

Comment: For people that downvote, please leave a comment on why you downvoted. The user cannot improve the quality of their answers by not knowing what they have done to make you downvote.   While I did not downvote, I think others did because no references and no legal standing.